# INSERT SQLite query don't work on Android

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite, expo

I'm making my first Expo app with SQLite database.

I have the 'subjects' table in my DB and i want to add subject from textInput. On IOS it works, but on Android don't.

When textInput is empty, after click add subject button console log with information that i cannot add empty subject works, so I think that there's problem with SQL query, can someone know why it isn't working?

```
const addSubject = (currentSubject) => {
        console.log(currentSubject)
        if(currentSubject && typeof currentSubject === "string" && currentSubject.trim() !== "") {
            db.transaction(tx => {
                tx.executeSql(
                    'INSERT INTO subjects (subject_name) values (?)', 
                    [currentSubject],
                    (txObj, resultSet) => {
                        let existingSubjects = [...subjects];
                        existingSubjects.push({subject_id: resultSet.insertId, subject_name: currentSubject});
                        setSubjects(existingSubjects);
                        console.log('Subject added!');
                        setCurrentSubject(undefined);
                    },
                    (txObj, error) => console.log('Subject didnt added -> ' + error)
                );
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('Cannot add empty subject!')
        }
    }
```

Here is the logcat when I click the adding button:

```
03-18 19:51:30.723  1271  1271 D TaplEvents: TIS / TouchInteractionService.onInputEvent: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=465.9746, y[0]=754.92773, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=8700081, downTime=8699994, deviceId=4, source=0x5002, displayId=0, eventId=877171131 }
03-18 19:51:30.730   443 10854 D audioserver: FGS Logger Transaction failed
03-18 19:51:30.730   443 10854 D audioserver: -129
03-18 19:51:30.891   443   526 D audioserver: FGS Logger Transaction failed
03-18 19:51:30.891   443   526 D audioserver: -129
```

Comment: this is not a invalid code. even SO's syntax highlighting tells you that

Comment: this is syntax of my code (i have done a mistake adding it here)

Comment: Please edit your question and post the log messages from logcat. There isn't enough information here to help you.